# "Function-level linking" (i.e. COMDAT generation) in MASM assembly?

Tags: visual-c++, masm, assembly

Is there any way to make MASM generate COMDATs for functions, so that unused functions are removed by the linker?

(i.e. I'm looking for the equivalents of `/Gy` for MASM.)

Comment: I always see assembly code organized with one function per source file, which has the same effect.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It doesn't help when doing that is impractical though.

Comment: If a function is not called, it is not linked into your executable or am I misunderstanding something?  If your source file has 20 functions, and you only use 10 of them, only 10 will be in your exe.

Comment: @Gunner: That's exactly what I **want**, but which **doesn't** happen in MASM.

Comment: Put the functions in a static library, the linker will only pull in the functions that are used.

Comment: @Gunner: Are you *sure* that makes a difference? Isn't a static library just a bunch of object files?

Comment: Are you using MASM or MASM32?  For example, MASM32 has a static library full of functions like atodw, ltok, szLen etc..  The lib contains MANY functions.  Now when I do: includelib masm32.lib, ALL of the functions it contains does not go into my exe, ONLY the ones that I call are linked into my exe.

Comment: @Gunner: I'm using MASM, but that's **unrelated**. The mistake you're making is thinking that static libraries are somehow magical. They aren't. They are pretty much a concatenation of a bunch of object files, and in your case, it is very likely that there is no more than 1 function per object file. If there were more, you would pull in *all* of the functions inside each object file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not straightforward, but doable; discussed [here](http://www.asmcommunity.net//forums/topic/?id=9910) and [here](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20040212035208/http://www.launcherasm.com/technical/comdats.html).

The first step involves putting each function into a separate segment with names like .text$a, .text$b, etc. This way, the assembler won't unite them into a single .text section, but the linker eventually will; there's a special rule in Microsoft linkers regarding the stuff past the $ character in the section name. The assembler will emit an .obj file with multiple code sections. I've tried that, I can confirm that it does. At least one flavor of MASM does. :)

Then they suggest running an utility over an object file that will mark your sections as COMDATs. The said utility seems to be lost to time and bit decay, but its action can be roughly deduced. It reads and parses a COFF .obj file, goes through sections and slaps a COMDAT flag on all .text sections. I assume it's just a flag; could be more. As a first step to its recreation, I'd suggest compiling a C file with /Gy then without, and comparing the two .obj files via some low-level PE/COFF browser. I didn't go this far, since my scenario was rather different.